# I can't find local folder in Magento 1.8.0.0 directory

Tags: magento, local, contact-form, magento-1.8

I am trying to create new custom contact form in Magento 1.8.0.0.

One of the steps is to create app/code/**local**/CustomContact/etc/config.xml

The problem I am facicing that I cant find local folder in the directory, I try to created I got errors at front end and back end.

I only found "community" and "core" folders in "app" folder.

it seems that in this new version of Magento the local folder is not there.

I want to know if there is another way to create Custom Contact form or if it is the same way then local folder should be some where else or I have to create the files in other folder.

If any one can help it would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What error gives you when you try to create local folder?

Comment: I don't remember that, what I remember is I couldn't get access to back end or front end. I have remove the local folder with it's contents to get back to normal access. But do I have to create it or it should be there? Thanks for replay

Comment: I am trying again the steps from the reference website: http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/magento-email/magento-custom-email-contact-form-with-notification-system/, found it at google, to see the error

Comment: you can see what error was that by checking the var/report folder.

Comment: I just repeated the steps again I got no error now, but the page "customcontactform.phtml" that I created it return empty with 3 column page, so it open the page but it is empty

Comment: I did exactly the same in this website: http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/magento-email/magento-custom-email-contact-form-with-notification-system/ and the page I have is: http://www.cabas-durables.fr/magento/customcontactform/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to create this folder yourself in modern versions of Magento.

Comment: I created the folder, and it works now, but the page is empty, even I have all the content in phtml file, here is the page: http://www.cabas-durables.fr/magento/customcontactform/

Comment: I copy the content of this page from the one I already done at the basic contact form in Magento, here it is http://www.cabas-durables.fr/magento/index.php/contacts/